# Circular dependency between classes PHP

Tags: php, profiling, circular-dependency

I am working on a project that involves profiling of the execution flow.
I've created a separate class for the profiler, and everytime I need to profile something I instantiate object of the profiler class and start monitoring.

```
$profiler=new Profiler($params);
$profiler->start();
//the code to be monitored//
$profiler->end();
```

The profiler class constructor checks the params to identify if the instance id to be logged or not. I've used a database table to store the profiling parameters.

```
void _construct($params){
 $this->checkConfig($params);
}
```

The checkConfig function executes a query on the database in order to fetch the configuration.

Now, as the team plans to monitor the database queries(which are executed through a query class in our case).  I tried the similar implementation for the executeQuery function:

```
class Query{
 public function executeQuery($queryParams){
   $profiler=new Profiler($params);
   $profiler->start();
   /*Execute query*/
   $profiler->end();
 }
}
```

This produces an interesting circular dependency. The query class starts a profiler, which fires a query and the query will ask for profiler again.

Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Inject the `Query` class into the profiler? Either way, you have errors in your code: the `executeQuery` method passes a non-existent `$params` variable to the `Profiler` constructor

Comment: I had the same problem when I implemented listeners for my DB class. When I implemented and registered a listener with DB queries the listener got triggered again in the listener so I ended up in an endless loop.

What I then implemented in the DB class is a `muteListener()` function which when set to `true` stopped listeners from being called. So in my listener before I fired a DB query I set `muteListener(true)` and after the query to ? false` again.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem the params var is just for demo purpose. The executequery function will pass some real information to find out whether or not the current query is to be profiled.

Comment: @nullPointer: Either way, the `Query` class shouldn't handle both the querying and its own logging, that's a violation of the SRP. Inject dependencies, and if you have circular dependencies, chances are you're not going about your business in the right way

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem the objective is to profile all the queries running in the system. As all the queries running in the system are handled by a single class, we aim to monitor the query time. It doesn't look like violation of the SRP principle to me as profiling is a separate class and we just need to start and end the profiling whenever a query is executed and the rest is handled by profiler class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is having similar issue, this is the workaround i built to solve the issue.

```
class Query{
   public function executeQuery($queryParams){
   static $checkProfiler;
   if(!isset($checkProfiler)){
     $profiler=new Profiler($params);
     $checkProfiler=1;
   }
   $profiler->start();
   /*Execute query*/
   $profiler->end();
   unset($checkProfiler);
 }
}
```

The start and end methods check if the profiler is active or not. Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it solved my issue.